# Extraer información de una tabla

Tags: r

Estoy intentando extraer de esta tabla

```
   RFO:

   DP=252;AD=1,243;VDB=1.04556e-09;SGB=-0.693147;RPB=1;MQB=1;MQSB=0.619406;BQB=1;MQ0F=0;AC=2;AN=2;DP4=1,0,117,127;MQ=40
   DP=248;AD=0,221;VDB=0.0177027;SGB=-0.693147;MQSB=0.203823;MQ0F=0;AC=2;AN=2;DP4=0,0,200,22;MQ=39
   DP=247;AD=0,222;VDB=0.0131104;SGB=-0.693147;MQSB=0.203823;MQ0F=0;AC=2;AN=2;DP4=0,0,200,22;MQ=39
   DP=34;AD=1,7;VDB=0.000100657;SGB=-0.636426;RPB=1;MQB=1;MQSB=1;BQB=1;MQ0F=0;ICB=1;HOB=0.5;AC=1;AN=2;DP4=0,1,7,0;MQ=28
   DP=248;AD=1,169;VDB=0.406213;SGB=-0.693147;RPB=1;MQB=1;MQSB=0.96677;BQB=1;MQ0F=0;AC=2;AN=2;DP4=0,1,120,50;MQ=32
```

Los valores DP4 con cada uno de los digitos que tiene.
He intentado usar esta función para extraerlos pero sin exito:

```
   RFO <- RFO %>% 
      mutate(TOTAL_DEPTH= {str_extract(INFO, "DP4=[A-Z][0-9]{4,5}[A-Z]?")}
      mutate(TOTAL_DEPTH= {str_extract(INFO, "DP4=[A-Z][0-9]{4,5}[A-Z]?") %>% 
      str_remove("DP4=") %>%
       as.numeric() }  )
```

Además cuando uso esta función:

```
     RFO <- RFO %>% 
     mutate(TOTAL_DEPTH= {str_extract(INFO, "DP4=[0-9]*")}
     mutate(TOTAL_DEPTH= {str_extract(INFO, "DP4=[0-9]*") %>% 
     str_remove("DP4=") %>%
     as.numeric() }  )
```

Se me genera una columna (TOTAL_DEPTH) con solo el primer digito de DP4 y me gustaría recoger los cuatro digitos.

¿Dónde está mi fallo?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Quizás que te has dejado algúna llave **}** por cerrar?

Comment: No, eso ha sido error mio a la hora de copiar el script (ya está editado) pero cuando añado la llave me sale la columna en blanco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es recuperar los 4 valores de la clave `DP4`. La forma más sencilla que se me ocurre es:

```
RFO %>% 
    bind_cols(
        as_tibble(
            str_match(.$INFO, "DP4=(\\d*),(\\d*),(\\d*),(\\d*);")[,-1]
            )
    )
```

Detalle:

- Podemos aprovechar que [`str_match()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_match) a diferencia de [`str_extract()`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_extract.html), permite extraer además del patrón, los grupos encontrados, de modo tal, que podemos usar grupos de captura para los valores numéricos de esta forma: `str_match(.$INFO, "DP4=(\\d*),(\\d*),(\\d*),(\\d*);")`
- Lo anterior nos devuelve una matriz, dónde la primer columna es el patrón completo y las siguientes son los grupos capturados. Integramos estos datos al `data.frame` original transformando la matriz a un `tibble` y luego  uniendo éste como columnas mediante [`bind_cols()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.4.3/topics/bind)